# How to access main window from view controllers in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create a custom view controller named `HomeViewController` which inherits from `UIViewController`. In main application delegate, I show it by calling `[window addSubview:homeViewController.view]` inside function `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. Yeah, everything works fine.

Now I add a button into the `HomeViewController` xib file. When I click on it, I want the `window` to remove the current view and add another `navigationController` instead. I make a function inside `HomeViewController.m` and link to the button but I don't know how to access the property `window` from there. `window` is a local variable inside the main app delegate and button click handler is inside `HomeViewController`. I'm thinking of doing the similar thing as above which is to add `navigationController.view` as subview of `window`.

Sorry! I'm very new to this iphone app development. I don't really get the big picture of how the application flow should be. Perhaps something's wrong with the structure of my project?

Comment: Instead of `[window addSubview:homeViewController.view] ` it should probably be `window.rootViewController = homeViewController;`

Answer (score 15):

You can access main window any where in your app using below line

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0]
```

Comment: Note that this is not necessarily the window containing the view controller any more. As of iOS13, apps may have multiple scenes which each may have their own window. Apps may also (rarely) have more than one window for a single scene. In any case, it's not 100% safe to assume that the window at index zero is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

`[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]` might help you to access `window` property of a delegate.

`AppDelegate` is your delegate class name.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to cast the delegate to access the window.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an extension to UIViewController. In Swift:

```
extension UIViewController {

    var window : UIWindow {
        return UIApplication.shared.windows.first!
    }

}
```

Now you can access it from within any view controller. For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.window.tintColor = .orange
}
```

Ostensibly you should have a window, so you should be able to safely force unwrap the window, however, you can just make it optional if you are doing something different with your window hierarchy:

```
extension UIViewController {

    var window : UIWindow? {
        return UIApplication.shared.windows.first
    }

}
```

Implementation using optionals:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let window = self.window {
        window.tintColor = .orange
    }
}
```